# closed-form of series

Tags: discrete-mathematics, closed-form

***Is there a closed form of this series?***

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{-r}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^n}{n!} \sum_{\rho=0}^{n/2} \frac{\frac{n}{2}!}{\rho! \left(\frac{n}{2}-\rho\right)!}Q^{\frac{n}{2}-\rho}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-Q)^k}{\Gamma(\alpha k+\frac{3}{2})}\times \frac{\Gamma(\alpha k+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2})}{\Gamma(\alpha k+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}-\alpha \rho)}t^{\alpha k+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}-\alpha \rho}$$
Is there a closed form in the form of Wright or Mittag-Leffler functions or the product of these two?
r is infinitely negative to infinite positivity. $a=\frac{i\hbar}{2m}$, $Q=\frac{A}{\hbar}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}-\frac{\pi B^{2} m}{4 \hbar^{2}}$, A and B are Coefficients and m is mass. $\alpha$ is between zero and one.

Comment: Can you at least transcribe this into MathJax?

Comment: Why can not anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have any constraints on $a$, $r$, $Q$, or $\alpha$?

Comment: Are you sure you mean to be using $(n/2)!$ for odd $n$?

Comment: This series is obtained using convolution theorem for inverse Laplace transform. That is, it is obtained from this statement.L^{-1}(\frac{s^{\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{s^{\alpha}+Q}})\star L^{-1}(exp(\frac{-r}{\sqrt{a}}\sqrt{s^{\alpha}+Q}))After calculating Laplace's inverse and convolution theorom, I got the question. Is the given series a closed form?

Comment: In fact, the quoted question is obtained from this , L^{-1}(\frac{s^{\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{s^{\alpha}+Q}})\s‌​tar L^{-1}(exp(\frac{-r}{\sqrt{a}}\sqrt{s^{\alpha}+Q})).Maybe my calculations are wrong?

Answer (score 1):

(This is not currently a complete answer.)

Call the OP's function $f(t)$.  (Why does no one name the functions they want to talk about?)  Let the operator $D^\mu$ be the fractional derivative operator with respect to $t$.  For $\mu \geq 0$ and $z >-1$, 
$$  D^\mu t^z= \frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{\Gamma(z+1-\mu)}t^{z-\mu}  \text{,}  $$
so, with the parameter constraints mostly revealed in comments, we have $\alpha \rho \in [0,n/2]$ and $\alpha k + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\alpha}{2} \in (0,\infty)$, so
$$  D^{\alpha \rho} t^{\alpha k+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha k+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2})}{\Gamma(\alpha k+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}-\alpha \rho)}t^{\alpha k+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}-\alpha \rho}  $$
and we obtain
$$ f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{-r}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^n}{n!} \sum_{\rho=0}^{n/2} \frac{\frac{n}{2}!}{\rho! \left(\frac{n}{2}-\rho\right)!}Q^{\frac{n}{2}-\rho}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-Q)^k}{\Gamma(\alpha k+\frac{3}{2})}  D^{\alpha \rho} t^{\alpha k+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}}  \text{.}  $$
The series in $k$ is a power series in $t^\alpha$, so we exchange the derivative and the sum (keeping the same radius of convergence).  \begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-Q)^k}{\Gamma(\alpha k+\frac{3}{2})}  D^{\alpha \rho} t^{\alpha k+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}} &= D^{\alpha \rho} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-Q)^k}{\Gamma(\alpha k+\frac{3}{2})} t^{\alpha k+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}}  \\
&= D^{\alpha \rho} t^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-Q t^\alpha)^k}{\Gamma(\alpha k+\frac{3}{2})}  \\
&= D^{\alpha \rho} t^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}} E_{\alpha, \frac{3}{2}}(-Q t^\alpha)  \text{,}
\end{align*}
where $E_{\alpha, \beta}(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{\Gamma(\alpha k + \beta)}$ is (one of) the [Mittag-Leffler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function)(s).  Since $\alpha$ and $3/2$ are both positive, our $E$ is an entire function.  So now we have
\begin{align*}
f(t) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{-r}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^n \frac{\frac{n}{2}!}{n!} \sum_{\rho=0}^{n/2} \frac{1}{\rho!}(D^{\alpha})^{\rho} \frac{Q^{\frac{n}{2}-\rho}}{\left(\frac{n}{2}-\rho\right)!} \cdot  t^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}} E_{\alpha, \frac{3}{2}}(-Q t^\alpha)  \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{-r}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^n \frac{2^{-n}\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2})} \sum_{\rho=0}^{n/2} \frac{1}{\rho!}(D^{\alpha})^{\rho} \frac{Q^{\frac{n}{2}-\rho}}{\left(\frac{n}{2}-\rho\right)!} \cdot  t^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}} E_{\alpha, \frac{3}{2}}(-Q t^\alpha)
\end{align*}

... and it's too late here for me to continue.  If anyone else wants to continue, be my guest.  (The $\rho$ summation is rather similar to something like a truncated Maclaurin series.)